# MediaPlayer broken in Android 6

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediaplayer, openframeworks

In our player we are using media player feature to render into a SurfaceTexture that is used in jni opengl layer to render dynamic textures.

Everything runs OK in Android 4 & 5, but not in Android 6 (with the same code).

The workflow is very easy.

First thing is load movie from URL:

```
public void loadMovie(String moviePath){
    try {
        if(mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 

            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(bIsLooping);
            mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnTimedTextListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this); 

           surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texNumber);
           surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
           surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
    
           mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);   
        } 

        bIsLoaded = false;

        duration = 0.0f; 
        width = height = 0;

        mediaPlayer.reset();

        if (moviePath.startsWith("android.resource://")){
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activity, Uri.parse(moviePath));
        } else if (moviePath.contains("obb://")) {
            String obbFileEntry = moviePath.replace("obb://", "");
            int idx0 = obbFileEntry.indexOf("/");
            int idx1 = obbFileEntry.indexOf("/", idx0 + 1);

            int mainVersion = Integer.parseInt(obbFileEntry.substring(0,idx0));
            int patchVersion = Integer.parseInt(obbFileEntry.substring(1+idx0, idx1));
            obbFileEntry = obbFileEntry.substring(idx1 + 1);

            ZipResourceFile obbFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(activity, mainVersion, patchVersion);
            AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = obbFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(obbFileEntry);
            if (null != assetFileDescriptor) {
                Log.d("[OFAndroidVideoPlayer]", "Playing media resource '" +  obbFileEntry + " packaged in obb expansion file( " + mainVersion + ", " + patchVersion + ")");
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
            }
        } else if (moviePath.contains(".zip/")) { 
            String zipFilePath = moviePath.substring(0, moviePath.lastIndexOf(".zip") + ".zip".length());
            String zipFileEntry = moviePath.substring(zipFilePath.length() + 1);

            ZipResourceFile zipFile = new ZipResourceFile(zipFilePath);

            AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = zipFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(zipFileEntry);
            if (null != assetFileDescriptor) {
                Log.d("[OFAndroidVideoPlayer]", "Playing media resource '" +  zipFileEntry + " packaged in zip file: " + zipFilePath);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
            }
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(moviePath);
        }

        mediaPlayer.prepare(); 

        width = mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
        height = mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
        duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

        //setVolume(volume);
        this.mediaPath = moviePath;
    } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("[OFAndroidVideoPlayer]","Illegal state with " + moviePath + " (" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e("[OFAndroidVideoPlayer]","I/O exception with " + moviePath + " (" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
        this.fixMediaPlayerIOExceptionCounter += 1;

        if (this.fixMediaPlayerIOExceptionCounter < 2) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
            loadMovie(moviePath);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("[OFAndroidVideoPlayer]","Couldn't load " + moviePath + " (" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
    }       
}
```

After registering a mediaplayer listener we are to control when mediaplayer is ready:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d("[ofxAndroidVideo]","[onPrepared] Entering method.");

    duration = (0.1f < duration)? duration: mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    width = (0 != width)? width: mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
    height = (0 != height)? height: mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();

    bIsLoaded = true;
    if(bAutoResume) {
        setPositionMS(movieResumeTime);
        bAutoResume = false;
        play();
    }
}
```

And update texture in surface texture loop:

```
@Override
public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture arg0) {
    synchronized(this){
        if(surfaceTexture != null) {
            surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
        }
}
```

The problem with Android 6 is that no listener callbacks are called after mediaplayer creation, prepare,...

It seems like the internal state of mediaplayer were wrong or broken or always in idle state and some internal working threads were not created/initialized.

I could not find any error traces in logcat.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should look into a library called "ExoPlayer" in my experience the performance and device support is much greater then using MediaPlayer or VideoView. Can still be output onto a SurfaceTexture or TextureView with some modification. Which works best for you cause.

Comment: We also have a alternative implementation with exoplayer, as i read and understand with local media sources uses standard android mediaplayer to render, so the problem is the same. Is it right?.

Comment: I do not believe that is correct. I have used ExoPlayer to rende/play locally saved videos. Have also used a customized version of ExoPlayer to edit local videos.